# Updating multiple records with different columns set

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to know if I can/how to update multiple records with different columns set in a single query.

So I have a table

```
Test {
   id integer
   name varchar
   age integer
}
```

Then for test1 and test 2 i have

```
test1 = Test {id=1, name="Joe"}
test2 = Test {id=2, age=22}
```

Is it possible to have a single query to update both of these even though each is updating a different column?

If i have multiple objects that all have the same fields something like the following works:

```
UPDATE test as t 
SET id = u.id, age = u.age, name = u.name 
FROM (VALUES (1, 21, 'Ronan'),(2, 65, 'Conor') ) 
AS u(id, age, name) 
WHERE u.id = t.id
```

Anyone able to clear this up for me? Im using Postgres if that makes a difference

Answer (score 1):

An update **always** sets each column listed and none not listed. So there is no direct way of updating different columns in a single statement0. However you can do so indirectly by specifying `null` for the columns you do not want updated then using the `coalesce` function to set those columns to their existing values (it cannot however set a value to null). Something like:  (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=159e9021d786b89034b3c444e9bd2755))

```
with new_val (id, name, age) as 
     ( values (1, null, 40) 
            , (2,'Paul',null) 
     ) 
update test  t
   set name = coalesce( nv.name, t.name) 
     , age  = coalesce( nv.age, t.age) 
  from new_val nv
 where t.id = nv.id;
```

The question becomes: Is it really worth it?  This could become quite messy if needed on more than a couple columns and/or rows. Seems specific updates for specific columns is both easier and safer.